# Difference in がない vs じゃない in na adjectives

Tags: grammar

For example, I have seen 元気じゃない and 元気がない, and now I'm wondering what is the difference between the two?

ありがとうございます

Comment: The 元気 in 元気がない is not an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

彼は元気じゃない ->　He is not [a] 元気 (lively) [person].

彼は元気がない　-> There is no 元気 (energy) in him. -> He is felling down.

Comment: The grammatical explanation is correct, but both 元気がない and 元気じゃない mean both "is not a lively person" and "is feeling down" depending on the context.